# Database restore error : "There is no item named 'dump.sql' in the archive"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, odoo, pg-dump, odoo-11

We have a database that runs on the Odoo.sh platform.

I downloaded database backup from Odoo.sh and I tried restore in my localhost. But I get an error like this :

Database restore error : "There is no item named 'dump.sql' in the archive"

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and supply the **exact** command you used to restore the backup. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Did you look into you backup ZIP file? Is there a dump.sql in it?

Comment: I solved this problem like this:

Firstly , I downloaded a backup of a database running in my localhost.
After, I compared this backup to the contents of the backup file I received from the database in Odoo.sh. Fİnally, I made the contents of the Odoo.sh zip file the same as the contents of the zip file I got from localhost. And this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ray Carnes explains the solution on https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/database-restore-error-there-is-no-item-named-dump-sql-in-the-archive-odoo-v11-134524

> From the BUILDS tab, select the box representing the database you
>   want, and from the KEBAB (three dots in a vertical line) menu, choose
>   DOWNLOAD DUMP.